# sql join resultset into a single row

Tags: php, sql, join

I have a "profiles" table with

1. userid
2. key
3. key_value

obviously userid can have many rows
when a user logs in, I store userdata in a session_var
the query uses 3 tables:

1. users
2. profiles
3. openid

I had this,

```
$sql = "SELECT op.provider, g . * , gp . *, CONCAT(g.firstname, ' ', g.lastname) AS fullname
    FROM openid AS op
    INNER JOIN users AS g ON g.userid = op.userid
    INNER JOIN profiles AS gp ON gp.userid = op.userid
    WHERE op.openid =$openid";
```

but it returns multiple rows with duplicate data depending how many rows there are in the "profiles" table

This is not what I want. I need all the data in one row if that is possible

What is the most efficient solution? I also need it to store in a php array. How does php handle duplicate keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like a `distinct` :

```
$sql = "SELECT distinct op.provider, g . * , gp . *, CONCAT(g.firstname, ' ', g.lastname) AS fullname
    FROM openid AS op
    INNER JOIN users AS g ON g.userid = op.userid
    INNER JOIN profiles AS gp ON gp.userid = op.userid
    WHERE op.openid =$openid";
```

That or you use a `group by` with the columns you want to have data grouped by.

Lastly, if you want to return multiple rows of data into a single field (but they are different) you could use a mysql `group_concat()` function to do so:

```
mysql> select * from first;
+------+-------+
| id   | title |
+------+-------+
|    1 | aaaa  |
|    2 | bbbb  |
|    3 | cccc  |
+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select group_concat(id) as IDs, group_concat(title) as Titles from first;
+-------+----------------+
| IDs   | Titles         |
+-------+----------------+
| 1,2,3 | aaaa,bbbb,cccc |
+-------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Okay, I added some extra rows to my example table like this:

```
mysql> select * from first;
+------+-------+
| id   | title |
+------+-------+
|    1 | aaaa  |
|    2 | bbbb  |
|    3 | cccc  |
|    4 | NULL  |
|    5 | eeee  |
+------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and now a `group_concat` returns this:

```
mysql> select group_concat(id) as IDs, group_concat(title) as Titles from first;
+-----------+---------------------+
| IDs       | Titles              |
+-----------+---------------------+
| 1,2,3,4,5 | aaaa,bbbb,cccc,eeee |
+-----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But you can add a nice placeholder using the `coalesce()` function nicely like this:

```
mysql> select group_concat(id) as IDs, group_concat(coalesce(title,'NoValueSpecial')) as Titles from first;
+-----------+------------------------------------+
| IDs       | Titles                             |
+-----------+------------------------------------+
| 1,2,3,4,5 | aaaa,bbbb,cccc,NoValueSpecial,eeee |
+-----------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

The `coalesce()` function looks at either multiple columns or a value you manually enter like I did and returns a great identifier to spot your missing field. It will evaluate left to right for the null values.

Comment: it still returns two rows ( because I have two rows in profiles)

Comment: @Richard You might want to use the `group_concat` function I added to the answer to group those individual records together into one row.

Comment: I don't know about group by, but group concat is interesting if I can make it into a twodimensional array ( the userid would be the same, but I need to assemble the keys and corresponding values) , do you have an example for a group by?

Comment: @Richard The group by is normally along with aggregate functions like `sum()` and can be used to group other columns, but if used without any aggregate functions, it removes identical rows of data. It likely isn't of much use to you in this case.

Comment: I like the group_concat function. I wil explode it in php together with the values field. Do I need to watch out for using this function in terms of when there are empty values in the field and when the values don't match up anymore with the keys.

Comment: @Richard Yeah, nulls will be omitted in a group_concat which can cause the order to become messed up. Will add an edit to help you out though.

Comment: had to do something in between..thank you @Fluffeh..I can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [GROUP CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to create a string that PHP can parse afterwards using [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
$sql = "SELECT distinct op.provider, g . * , GROUP_CONCAT(gp.`key` , '=' , gp.key_value SEPARATOR '&'), CONCAT(g.firstname, ' ', g.lastname) AS fullname
    FROM openid AS op
    INNER JOIN users AS g ON g.userid = op.userid
    INNER JOIN profiles AS gp ON gp.userid = op.userid
    WHERE op.openid =$openid";
```

The output for the profiles columns will be something like: "key1=value1&key2=value2".